# 1s data to 10 minute statistics using timestamp

Tags: r, average, subset

I have measurements of wind speed and wind direction every second. I need to reduce the data to 10 minute averages, also saving min, max, and sd values.

The block of 10 minutes should be at specific intervals, for example between time 10:10 and 10:20 should have the time stamp 10:20 in the new data.frame.
Sometimes there are gaps in the measurements, therefore a 10' period with less than 600 measurements should be discarded.
Here is how the input dataframe looks like:

```
     date        time    speed        angle
1 2015-02-24 10:33:20.00 7.415 -17.65045166
2 2015-02-24 10:33:21.00 6.650   0.06921746
3 2015-02-24 10:33:22.00 6.650 -19.54238892
4 2015-02-24 10:33:23.00 7.415 -46.76791382
5 2015-02-24 10:33:24.00 6.650  84.60681152
6 2015-02-24 10:33:25.00 6.650   7.41780472
```

Here is what it should look at the end:

```
    date        time    speedAvg angleAvg  speedMax speedMin speedSd
1 2015-02-24 10:30:00 
2 2015-02-24 10:40:00 
3 2015-02-24 10:50:00 
4 2015-02-24 11:00:00 
5 2015-02-24 11:10:00 
6 2015-02-24 11:20:00
```

So, I think that the way to do this is to use the function subset on the date-time variables to create a dataframe that can be used to calculate the values. Use rbind at the end of the loop. 
I can't figure out how to use subset on specific time intervals.
Also, advices are welcome on a more elegant solution.

Comment: It seems like I can't edit my own question...:-/ I forgot to mention that I am using R. I was not allowed to give a more specific tag because I don't have reputation to make new tags.

Answer (score 0):

I proceeded as follows:

1. Build a time series "X" with all 1 second timestamps, i.e. without the gaps.
2. Fill in the measurements from the data frame "data".
3. Use the data from the time series "X" to calculate the 10 minute statistics and write the results into a new timeseries "Y".
4. Remove the rows from "Y" where some data is missing.

.

```
library(timeDate)
library(timeSeries)

data <- read.table( filename, header=TRUE )

########################################################################
# Build a timeSeries "X" from the data.frame "data":

tm <- as.timeDate( strptime(paste(as.character(data$date),as.character(data$time)),
                            format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.00",
                            tz = "GMT"),
                   zone = "GMT")

t <- timeSequence(start(tm),end(tm),by="secs")

X <- timeSeries( data.frame( speed = rep(NA,length(t)),
                             angle = rep(NA,length(t)) ) )

setTime(X) <- t

X[tm]$speed <- data$speed
X[tm]$angle <- data$angle

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Restrict the timestamps to 10 minute steps:

m <- seq( from = which.max(format(t[601:length(t)],"%M:%S")=="00:00"),
          to   = length(t),
          by   = 600      )

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Calculate 10 minute statistics:

Y <- timeSeries( data.frame(
  speed_avg = sapply(m,function(m){mean(na.omit(X$speed[(m-599):m]))}),
  speed_sd  = sapply(m,function(m){sd(na.omit(X$speed[(m-599):m]))}),
  speed_min = sapply(m,function(m){min(na.omit(c(X$speed[(m-599):m],Inf)))}),
  speed_max = sapply(m,function(m){max(na.omit(c(X$speed[(m-599):m],-Inf)))}),
  angle_avg = sapply(m,function(m){mean(na.omit(X$angle[(m-599):m]))}) ) )

setTime(Y) <- t[m]
Y <- Y[complete.cases(Y),]

write.table(Y,filename_10min)
```

Since a large amount of data was necessary, I used the following script to create example data:

```
library(timeDate)

#######################################################################
# Create example data

set.seed(1)

t_start <- as.timeDate("2015-01-01 00:00:00")
t_end   <- as.timeDate("2015-01-03 13:00:00")

t <- timeSequence(t_start,t_end,by="sec")

data <- data.frame( date  = format(t,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                    time  = format(t,"%H:%M:%S.00"),
                    speed = 6 + sin((1:length(t))/500) + sample(-10:10,length(t),replace=TRUE)/15,
                    angle = sample(-900:900,length(t),replace=TRUE)/10 )

# Some values are missing:
data[8823:11580,] <- NA
data[13585:18801,] <- NA
data[sample(1:nrow(data),0.1*nrow(data)),] <- NA
data <- na.omit(data)

write.table( data, filename, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this easily using dplyr by doing the following:

1. Create a new column in your data frame with the 10 mins interval start time(hour and min) for each row.
2. Use dplyr functions to aggregate the data easily and filter out rows with data less than 600 time points.
   [here is a quick intro to dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)
   Assuming your data is stored in an object called X:

> 

```
library(dplyr)
X$time <- as.character(X$time)
X$hourmin <- substr(X$time, 1, 4)
X$time <- paste(X$hourmin, "0:00", sep = "")
X <- X %>% group_by(date, time)
       %>% summarize(
           speedAvg = mean(speed, na.rm=T)
          ,angleAvg = mean(angle, na.rm=T)
          ,speedMax = max(speed, na.rm=T)
          ,speedMin = min(speed, na.rm=T)
          ,speedSd = sd(speed, na.rm=T)
          ,datapoint_count = n())
  %>% filter(datapoint_count >= 600))

#remove datapoint_count column.
X <- X[, -8]
```

Comment: @mra68 Why data_point > 0, he did say he wanted to discard 10 min intervals with less than 600 observations so hence, data_point >= 600. data_point counts the total number of observations in each 10 min interval.

Comment: I'm afraid with "data_point>=600" almost nothing will survive. And there is no good reason to throw away the hole 10 minutes if only 1 second is missing.

Comment: Whether anything will survive or not is out of the scope of this question. You can discuss specifics of the analysis with @GeorgeLongIsland since he chose to impute his missingness by discarding them.

Comment: I implemented this solution and worked well with minor changes to avoid overwriting columns (so I can see what is happening). And yes I lowered the minimum requirement to 400 data points to keep more data :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you click the green check mark by this to mark it as the answer so others know which answer to look at when they face a similar problem.